# How to change StackOverflow's Dark theme to Another?

Tags: themes

This might seem trivial but I can't find my way around.

I currently & excitedly use the new Dark theme designed here on SO. I would like to change the theme such as from Dark back to bright etc., depending on the time of the day and for my eyes.

On `stackoverflow.blog` there is a `toggle` to change but then navigating to `stackoverflow.com` it goes back to the dark theme. I couldn't find help in the 'help' section. Any other help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you login , go to your site preferences page here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences
You will see the options there.